# WPF 4 Embedded Fonts cause SLOW VS2010 Builds

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, fonts, expression-blend

After upgrading our VS2008 Project to VS2010 we found that VS would take 60 seconds before it appeared to actually begin building our project.

With VS 2008 our Project would build in 3 seconds.

I finally discovered that when we use Expression Blend 3/4 to embed a font into our Project, it slows down the build in VS 2010.

Has anyone got a solution to fix this?

We need 20 fonts embedded in our WPF application, and I CANNOT HANDLE waiting 60 seconds everytime I build my application.  For now if I exclude the Fonts folder from the Project it again builds in 3 seconds...

Comment: It sounds like it's regenerating the fonts with each new build. That's always going to take time. One possible solution is to just turn it off until you actually need it in a build. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765391/embedding-fonts-forces-silverlight-project-to-always-rebuild for another solution.

Comment: We moved the fonts to a satellite assembly and now we have no problems.  Once the EmbeddedFonts.dll is compiled it never recompiles, since we never change it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the Fonts as part of a separate resources DLL that you only compile when you make changes to the fonts. This way, you just include the DLL file to your project, and whenever you change the fonts, you use a deployment batch file to copy the dlls to the project, since it will need the actual files to run. This way, you don't rebuild fonts every time, you will also save the time it takes to rebuild them every time you build.

This approach also avoids you turning it off, and helps you separate the resources from the actual application.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for in still be able to work with Blend.  But I suppose we have the fonts embedded we need, so we shouldn't be changing them.

Comment: It will still work with blend. You build the project, you don't change anything to the sources, and then move the DLLs to the folder where you put them in your VS project, and you won't have any issues.